# Black flickering on Honeycomb WebView

Tags: android

I've run into a problem when using `<input type="password">` fields in a WebView on Honeycomb devices.  Any time the view is scrolled, the screen flickers black and can even stay all black (except that it will draw the focused password field) once scrolling ends.  I've seen this on all three Honeycomb tablets I've checked.

I can load the same HTML in the Browser app and I do not see this issue.  I've tried changing many of the settings on the WebSettings/WebChromeClient/WebViewClient of the WebView and had no luck there.  I've loaded the code below on a Froyo tablet and this issue did not occur, so it seems like a Honeycomb specific issue.

Has anyone seen this before?  I'm at a loss on how to fix or workaround this issue currently.

Here's a short code sample that reproduces the issue.  Simply focus the password field and scroll up and down.  There's a password type input field and a text type input field, just to show that the issue does not occur with the text type field.  The `<div>` tag is there simply to make it easier to scroll around and see the issue, although the issue still occurs without the `<div>` tag.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class PasswordFieldTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        String html = "<html><body><div style=\"with: 120%; height: 200%; border: 20px dashed black;\">" +
            "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"passfield\"/><br/>" +
            "Text: <input type=\"text\" name=\"textfield\"/>" +
            "</div></body></html>";
        webview.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");

        setContentView(webview);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any luck in finding an answer?

Comment: No, haven't had any luck.  If you turn on hardware acceleration for the WebView, the problem goes away, but the performance for hardware accelerated WebViews isn't acceptable at this time, so it's not really a solution.  I've just moved my login screen to a native dialog.

Comment: i am facing same problem in android 4.1 ,so plaese tell me how to solve it so it will work on every android version??

Answer (score 6):

After trying everything suggested here, this finally worked for me on all the phones:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

AND:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
 webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
} else {
 webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Please let me know if you find a phone this doesn't work on.
Works with these phones:

- note2 (4.1.2)
- htc one x (4.0.4)
- galaxy s3 (4.3)
- nexus4 (4.3)

Comment: Thanks @GeneralKimi, That particular phone has some serious compatibility issues. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I've found the solution. Put WebView inside ScrollView and disable WebView scroll. Than, no black flickering, but have one another problem. If WebView occupies full screen, when you scroll big text in some moment no more text, only scroll. When I opened Gmail official application and seen same problem. I only say, bye... :D

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in honeycomb devices.

However this one worked for me -

```
Compatibility.getCompatibility().setWebSettingsCache(webSettings);
```

Make sure to implement a Compatibility layer, since following method doesn't work in SDK_INT < 11.

```
webViewInstance.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

List of solutions suggested are [here.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20446)

Comment: how to use this compatibility class??

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a android:cacheColorHint issue. Try setting it to transparent in the WebView's attribute set.

Comment: there's no such attribute?

Answer (score 0):

For me `android:layer="software"` in the xml layout file works fine.